# What is the correct use of "safety" and "security"?

Tags: word-choice, differences

I was chatting with three friends this evening, when one of them asked about the use of some english words (we are not native speakers):

> What is the difference between "security" and "safety"?

The other answered:

> "Safety" is about accidental causes, and "security" is about intentional causes.

Shortly after, some (confusing?) examples were given:

> - It is safe to cross the bridge, it won't break.
> - It is secure to cross the bridge, the dinosaurs aren't looking for food.
> - This bank is secure against thieves.
> - This bridge is safe against flood damage.

Could anyone clarify this for us?

Comment: The 2nd and 4th examples are very poor - most native speakers would reverse the words *safe* and *secure*. It's true we're more likely to speak of being *secure* against *"anticipated threats"*, and *safe* from *"unexpected mishaps"*, but your friend is rationalising this to a degree and direction that's misleading rather than explanatory.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

[I found a very interesting paper on the differences of *safe* and *secure*.](http://www.iot.ntnu.no/users/albrecht/rapporter/notat%20safety%20v%20security.pdf) Here's the summary:

[image]

Although the paper is mainly about these words in the economical context, I think it explains quite clearly the differences in general. If I were to summarize the above table into a single line, I would agree with your friend in that ***roughly***

> "Safety" is about accidental causes, and "security" is about intentional causes.

Comment: I very much disagree with the chart's claim that safety "hazards are observable, tangible and proximate" -- in fact if I had to choose between safety and security I'd choose the former if asked which was more likely to cover unobservable and intangible threats.  But the chart is otherwise good and I agree with your conclusion.

Comment: @Charles: Would you argue that *most* native speakers would choose *safety* to describe what covers unobservable and intangible threats? I think that the difference is quite subtle, even for native speakers.

Comment: I think that the majority of people who would make a distinction would choose safety, and probably a majority overall.  I'm not a good representative sample, though; I work in safety.

Comment: (FWIW, I gave you a +1.)

Comment: One could just as well make a case for saying *security* is about *the **sense** of being safe*, by which token *safety* is the result of either not encountering, or successfully dealing with, *insecurity*. After all, we all know that *a false sense of security* is exceptionally dangerous (i.e. - the opposite of *safe*). They're different words with many usages, some of which overlap. But the distinction here has little or no relevance to many if not most of those usages.

Comment: @FumbleFingers I think that is a good description as well: if you make sure your house is secure then you will feel safe at night!

Comment: @Charles Maybe it should say "observable *in principle*"? For example, safety systems in automobiles need a certain level of coverage (observability) of faults in order to meet particular safety levels.